# Probabilistic lower and upper-bounds for a certain random quartic form involving gaussian random matrices

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, st.statistics, random-matrices, free-probability

Let $d,m \to \infty$ (integers) with $m/d \to \rho \in (0, \infty)$. Let $C$ be a $d \times d$ psd matrix with $trace(C)=\mathcal O(1)$, and let $w_1,\ldots,w_m$ be iid uniformly distributed on the unit-sphere in $\mathbb R^d$. Consider the quartic form
$$
F := \frac{1}{m}\sum_{j,\ell=1}^m (w_j^\top w_\ell)(w_j^\top C w_\ell).
$$

> **Question.** What are good probabilistic lower and upper-bounds for $F$ only in terms of $\rho$ and the eigenvalues of $C$ ?

For example, the solution for the case where $C$ is **diagonal** will already be very helpful.

### Isotropic example

Thanks to this post https://mathoverflow.net/a/334219/78539, we know that if $C = (1/d) I_d$, then $F = m^{-1}\|WW^\top\|_F^2 = m^{-1}\sum_{j}\lambda_j(W W^\top)^2\overset{a.s}{\to} \langle \lambda^2\rangle_{\text{MP}(1/\rho)}$ (if I haven't made some scaling errors), where $\text{MP}(\gamma)$ is the Marchenko-Pastur law with parameter $\gamma$.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Why does knowing $E[w_jw_j^\top]$ allow to compute $\mathbb E[F]$ ?

Comment: I deleted my comment as there was a mistake. Use the trace trick, $w_l^Tw_j w_j^TC w_l = trace[w_jw_j^TCw_lw_l^T]$, by indendence of $w_j,w_l$ the expectation of the sum of non-diagonal terms is $m(m-1)/(md^2)trace[C]$. For the diagonal terms, same story with the simplification $w_j^Tw_j=1$. You can verify the answer using $\langle\lambda^2\rangle=mean^2+variance$ where mean/variance of the MP law are known and simple.

Comment: Would Gaussian iid entries be fine, or do you absolutely need uniform vectors on the sphere? In the Gaussian case the second moment of $E[F]-F$ shouldn't be out of reach.

Comment: No, I'm fine with gaussian iid. In fact, any log-concave isotropic distribution on $\mathbb R^d$ such that $\mathbb E[\|w_1\|^2] = 1$. Thanks in advance for estimate of variance of $F$ (which can be used to get concentration, via Chebychev inequality).

Comment: @jlewk Moments of $F-E[F]$ will presumably be very hard to compute without some clever trick (of which I'm not aware). Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: @jlewk Also do you have a reference fo the "mean/variance of the MP law" ? For example, I'm hesitating between $\langle \lambda^2\rangle = \rho+1$ and $\rho(\rho + 1)$., thought I think it should be the latter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://djalil.chafai.net/blog/2011/01/29/the-marchenko-pastur-law/ and equation (6) in https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.05001 are the first result that comes up in my favorite search engine.

Comment: Since the operator norm is bounded by the eigenvalues, I don't see why anything about it needs to specified explicitly. Generally I think the notation would be clearer rewriting the whole question as: Let $C$ be a $d\times d$ psd matrix, let $w_1, \ldots w_m$ be iid vectors uniformly distributed on the sphere in $R^d$, and let $F=\sum_{j,k=1}^m(w_j^\top w_k)(w_k^\top Cw_j)$. What are good probabilistic lower and upper bounds for $F$ in terms of $d$, $m$, and the eigenvalues of $C$?

Comment: Sure (see modification). The superficial condition on $\|C\|_{op}=\mathcal O(1/d)$ was a careless attempt to ensure the whole thing doesn't blow up. Indeed from some computations, it appears the important thing is the trace of $C$. That is all one should normally require, $trace(C) = \mathcal O(1)$. I think such a condition is necessary at the bare minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume iid $N(0,1)$ entries, assume $C$ diagonal, and focus first on the non-diagonal terms:

$G=\sum_j \sum_{l\ne j} w_j^Tw_l w_j^TCw_l
= \sum_{j\ne l, ik} w_{ji}w_{li} c_i w_{jk} w_{lk}$.
Write this quantity as
$$
\begin{split}
G=\sum_{j\ne l, i\ne k} w_{ji}w_{li} c_i w_{jk} w_{lk}
&+
\sum_{j\ne l, i=k} (w_{ij}^2-1)(w_{lj}^2 -1)c_i
\\
&+(w_{ij}^2-1)c_i + 
(w_{lj}^2 -1)c_i
+c_i
\end{split}
$$
This is a decomposition in uncorrelated polynomials (any two terms are uncorrelated), so that the second moment is
$$
E[(G-m(m-1)trace[C])^2]=\sum_{j\ne l, i \ne k} c_i^2
+
\sum_{j\ne l, i}(E[(Z^2-1)^2]^2 + 2 E[(Z^2-1)^2])c_i^2.
$$
$$= m(m-1)\|C\|_F^2((d-1)+E[(Z^2-1)^2]^2 + 2E[(Z^2-1)^2]).$$
The dominant term is of order $m^2d \|C\|_F^2$, while the mean is $m(m-1)trace[C]$. Hence $G/E[G]-1$ converges to 0 in probability (or in L2) provided that $E[G]^2 \gg Var[G]$, that is,
$$
m^2 trace[C] \gg \|C\|_F m \sqrt{d}.
$$

For the diagonal terms, we have
$\sum_j d w_j^TCw_j + \sum_{j} (\|w_j\|^2-d)w_j^TCw_j$.
The second term is negligible compared to the first one if you use $\chi^2$ concentration (e..g, Bernstein inequality) for $\|w_j\|^2-d$, while the first term has mean $md trace[C]$ and variance $2md^2\|C\|_F^2$.
Again, the mean dominates the standard deviation if and only if
$$
m d ~trace[C] \gg \sqrt m d \|C\|_F.$$ This is equivalent to the condition on the non-diagonal terms if $m\asymp d$.

Edit: since $\|C\|_F^2 \le trace[C]^2$ for $C$ psd, these conditions are always satisfied.